no domain link when ı launched my website on aws elasticbeanstalk

ı get some errors on aws elastic beanstalk and ı can not get domain link, my website contains data but ı didnt use database when ı do configurations but errors are not about database?
also ı get this error
November 19, 2024 11:34:18 (UTC+3)
INFO
Environment health has transitioned from Pending to No Data. Initialization in progress (running for 16 minutes). There are no instances```



